# Custom attribute goes in additional_attributes column

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

When I create a custom attribute in Magento2, at export this goes in additional_attributes column, is there a way to have a new column for every custom attribute? This makes it very difficult to prepare the import files.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import custom attributes in Magento2, you can add them as extra columns, or you can place them in the additional_attributes column. Either way will work. For example, if you have a custom "material" attribute, then you can just add a "material" column to the import file and it will import just fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Magento 2 extension from **BSS Commerce** for adding column in csv for additional attributes.
Here is a link :
[3 Minutes to Export Catalog Product with Custom Attributes in Magento 2](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-export-custom-product-attributes/)

You do have to configure an Admin setting for the module to tell it which fields to break out into their own columns, but it was easy to set up.